# ActiveRecord accessor dot(.) vs bracket([])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

With Active Record, we can access a value like

### method access

```
user = User.find(1)
user.name #=> 'John'
```

or

### hash access

```
user[:name] #=> 'John'
```

I just wonder when to use which, or is there any best practice out there?
Personally I'd prefer `method access` because I feel that is more like ruby way. However when I see code by others, I face the `hash access`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails convention is to use [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read#`read_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute) (dot notation), rather than its alias [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#`[]`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D), which:

> Returns the value of the attribute identified by `attr_name` after it
>   has been typecast (for example, `“2004-12-12”` in a date column is cast
>   to a date object, like `Date.new(2004, 12, 12)`). It raises
>   `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` if the identified attribute is
>   missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you mean whenever I access with the `#[]`, some typecast is occurred based on the column type. And if I didn't specify with `attr_name`, it raises an error.

Comment: @Toshi I've edited the answer a bit. Basically two methods are interchangeable, it's just that convention advices the first one :)

Comment: okay, now I got that. I just wonder  there are any cases that `#[]` would be better than dot notation. Maybe readability or something?

Comment: Difference would be, for example, that dot notation would raise an exception `undefined method` if you call non-existing method on an object, whereas `[:]` will just return `nil` (no exceptions). My personal preference is after dot notation especially because of readability :)

Comment: yep so the dot notation has basically two advantages 1. Ruby convention 2. readability. This is the last question, if I access data with method chain. You still use dot notation or `[:]` For example `user.account.uuid` or `user[:account][:uuid]`? pretty much personal preference?

Comment: @Toshi sure, convention remains for any amount of methods in the method's chain (so `user.account.uuid`) :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: In addition to what is mentioned above: Bracket notation is easier if you want to dynamically specify which attribute you are reading, such as `myobj[attr_to_fetch]`.  However, dot notation makes it a bit easier to use [Safe Navigation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator), such as `myobj&.some_attr`.  Doing the same in bracket notation is visually noisier: `myobj&.[](:some_attr)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise against using bracket notation as it breaks the inheritance hierarchy of method calls and makes refactoring harder.

If my model has an attribute `name`, and I decide I want to enhance the name every time someone reads it, a very idiomatic way to do that would be:

`def name
  "Awesome #{super}!"
end`

Any place in my app that uses the method version would work fine, any place that uses the `[]` notation would return raw database data. I could overwrite the `[]` but then I would need special conditions checking for specific attributes. The whole thing would be a nightmare.

Another scenario, let's say I had an attribute that used to be stored in the database, but after a while decide that it should be computed on the fly, and end up dropping the database column. With the method version all I would need to do is add methods to my model. With the `[]` notation the process would be much much harder.

Also `[]` provides an insignificant performance improvement so though it looks like it's "closer" to the raw data it really isn't.

Comment: This question is the top response on Google right now and I don't think the accepted answer is technically correct. This answer is more correct.

Bracket notation will return what's in the database, that's a very key difference to dot notation.